# emacs use auto-complete-clang to autocomplete, it shows invalid member function

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, clang

I am using emacs24.1 and auto-complete-clang to do the C++ syntax complete , but when i trigger the autocomplete action , the droplist contains invalid member function which is not specified defined in the struct . How can i avoid this ?
My init.el define about auto-complete-clang.el

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/root/.emacs.d/plugins/auto-complete-1.3.1")
(require 'auto-complete)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "/root/.emacs.d/plugins/ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)
;;start after 3 characters were typed 
(setq ac-auto-start 3)
;;show menu immediately
(setq ac-auto-show-menu 0.3)
```

**Yeah, I know that the constructor,destructor and operator = are default, but i still don't want them to be showed because I donn't specified declared them.**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you say "invalid member function," are you referring to userInfo, ~userInfo, and operator= ?

Those are the default constructor, destructor, and assignment operator, respectively.  Every class will have one.  They're not invalid.  In fact they're required, and if you don't provide them the compiler will generate default ones.  For some more documentation on this, see http://cartan.cas.suffolk.edu/oopdocbook/opensource/derivedcdas.html

It may not be a good idea to suppress those members, because they're still reasonable completions.